# Why does {} as function argument not lead to ambiguity?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, overload-resolution

Consider this code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

enum class A
{
  X, Y
};

struct Test
{
  Test(const std::vector<double>&, const std::vector<int>& = {}, A = A::X)
  { std::cout << "vector overload" << std::endl; }

  Test(const std::vector<double>&, int, A = A::X)
  { std::cout << "int overload" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<double> v;
  Test t1(v);
  Test t2(v, {}, A::X);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Gc_w8i

This prints:

```
vector overload
int overload
```

Why does this not produce a compilation error due to ambiguous overload resolution? If the second constructor is removed, we get `vector overload` two times. How/by what metric is `int` an unambiguously better match for `{}` than `std::vector<int>`?

<sup>The constructor signature can surely be trimmed further, but I just got tricked by an equivalent piece of code and want to make sure nothing important is lost for this question.</sup>

Comment: If i recall corretly `{}` as a block of code, assigns 0 to variables - example:  
const char x = {};  is set to 0 (null char) , same for int etc.

Comment: @Seti That is what `{}` effectively does in certain special cases, but it's not generally correct (for starters, `std::vector<int> x = {};` works, `std::vector <int> x = 0;` does not). It's not as simple as "`{}` assigns zero".

Comment: Right, its not so simple, but it still assigns zero - thought i think that this beaviour is quite confusing and shouldnt be used really

Comment: @Seti `struct A { int x = 5; }; A a = {};` does not assign zero in any sense, it constructs an `A` with `a.x = 5`. This is unlike `A a = { 0 };`, which does initialize `a.x` to 0. The zero is not inherent to `{}`, it is inherent to how each type is default-constructed or value-initialized. See [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17.1), [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#list-3.11) and [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#aggr-5).

Comment: I still think that default-constructed value are confusing (requires you to check the behavior or keep much knowledge all the time)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's in **[over.ics.list]**, emphasis mine

> [6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.list#6) Otherwise, if the parameter is a non-aggregate class X and
>   overload resolution per [over.match.list] chooses a single best
>   constructor C of X to perform the initialization of an object of type
>   X from the argument initializer list:
>
> - If C is **not an initializer-list constructor and the initializer list has a single element** of type cv U, where U is X or a class derived
>     from X, the implicit conversion sequence has Exact Match rank if U is
>     X, or Conversion rank if U is derived from X.
> - **Otherwise, the implicit conversion sequence is a user-defined conversion sequence with the second standard conversion sequence an
>     identity conversion.**
>
> [9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.list#9) Otherwise, if the parameter type is not a class:
>
> - [...]
> - if the initializer list has no elements, the implicit
>     conversion sequence is the identity conversion. [ Example:
>
>   ```
>   void f(int);
>   f( { } ); // OK: identity conversion
>   ```
>
>   end example ]

The `std::vector` is initialized by constructor and the bullet in bold deems it a user defined converison. Meanwhile, for an `int`, this is the identity conversion, so it trumps the rank of the first c'tor.

Comment: Yes, seems accurate.

Comment: Interesting to see that this situation is explicitly considered in the standard. I would've really expected it to be ambiguous (and it looks like it could have easily been specified that way). I can't follow the reasoning in your last sentence - `0` has type `int` but not type `std::vector<int>`, how is that an "as if" wrt to the "untyped" nature of `{}`?

Comment: @MaxLanghof - The other way to look at it is that for non class types, it's not a user defined conversion by any stretch. In stead it's a direct initializer for the default value. Hence an identity in this case.

Comment: That part is clear. I'm surprised by the need for a user-defined conversion to `std::vector<int>`. As you said, I expected "the type of the parameter ends up deciding what's the type of the argument", and a `{}` "of type" (so to speak) `std::vector<int>` should not need (non-identity) conversion to initialize a `std::vector<int>`. The standard obviously says it does, so that's that, but it doesn't make sense to me. (Mind you, I'm not arguing that you or the standard are wrong, just trying to reconcile this with my mental models.)

Comment: Ok, that edit was not the resolution I hoped for, but fair enough. :D Thanks for your time!

Comment: @MaxLanghof - Deleted my ramblings because I'm struggling to put it into words clearly. Will revisit later when time permits.

Comment: Looking forward to that :)